# Service Applications and Google Analytics API V3: Server-to-server OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, jwt

I'm trying to make a server application to routinely pull Google Analytics data from my own GA account. Note, it is a personal, server-side application accessing my own data, i.e. *there is no end-user accessing this application.*

As such, I registered my application in the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/) as a **Service Application**, which gave me a **Client ID** and a **Private Key**. It is my understanding that Service Applications do NOT use **Application Secret** and **Redirect URL** as there is no end-user in this server-to-server authentication flow. Indeed, the Google API Console gave me no Secret and did not prompt me for a Redirect URL.

Unfortunately,  I can not figure out how to authenticate my Service Application within [Google's PHP Client API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/). There is extensive documentation on authenticating web applications **with** an end-user.

Google's documentation suggests [it is possible to authenticate server-to-server by signing a JWT request with the private key](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). I just can't figure out how to do within the PHP client API (although I've browsed the source and there's [definitely a script](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/auth/apiP12Signer.php) that signs a request with the private key.)

Am I missing something here? How can I perform authentication for a Service Application with my private key and the Google PHP client API?

*Edited for clarity*

Answer (score 107, accepted):

### UPDATE July 21st, 2012

Google Analytics API V3 now supports OAuth2 tokens returned by a .p12-signed JWT request. That is, **we can now use the Analytics API w/ service accounts**.

Currently pulling 4 years of day-by-day metrics, *just for the hell of it.*

Here's a quick 'n' dirty step-by-step:

1. Go to the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and create a new app
2. In the *Services* tab, flip the *Google Analytics* switch
3. In the *API Access* tab, click *Create an OAuth2.0 Client ID*

   - enter your name, upload a logo, and click *Next*
   - select the *Service account* option and press *Create client ID*
   - download your private key
4. Now you're back on the *API Access* page. You'll see a section called *Service account* with a *Client ID* and *Email address*

   - Copy the email address (something like *####@developer.gserviceaccount.com*)
   - Visit your [GA Admin](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#management/Accounts/) and **add this email as a user to your properties**
   - This is a must; you'll get cryptic errors otherwise.
5. Get the latest [Google PHP Client API](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) via Github

   ```
   git submodule add https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git google-api-php-client-read-only
   ```
6. Rock 'n' roll (thanks all for tips on updated class names):

   ```
   // api dependencies
   require_once(PATH_TO_API . 'Google/Client.php');
   require_once(PATH_TO_API . 'Google/Service/Analytics.php');

   // create client object and set app name
   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->setApplicationName(APP_NAME); // name of your app

   // set assertion credentials
   $client->setAssertionCredentials(
     new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(

       APP_EMAIL, // email you added to GA

       array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),

       file_get_contents(PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE)  // keyfile you downloaded

   ));

   // other settings
   $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);           // from API console
   $client->setAccessType('offline_access');  // this may be unnecessary?

   // create service and get data
   $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
   $service->data_ga->get($ids, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, $optParams);
   ```

<sub>*original workaround below*</sub>

---

> It seems that, despite ambiguous documentation, [most Google APIs do
>   not support service accounts yet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/NBQoOrtcC6A), including Google Analytics. They
>   cannot digest OAuth2 tokens returned by a .p12 signed JWT request. So,
>   as of right now, you *cannot use Google Analytics API V3 with a
>   service account*.
>
> **Workaround:**
>
> 1. In the [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?pli=1), create a **client** application.
> 2. Follow the steps in the [Google PHP Client API](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) examples to generate a `client_auth_url` using your `client_id`, `client_secret`,
>      and `redirect_uri`
> 3. Login to [Google](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth) using cURL. (Be sure to use a cookie file!)
> 4. Open the `client_auth_url` in cURL and complete the form. Make sure you set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);` and
>      `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);`     as the `authorization_code`
>      will be in the `Location:` header of the response.
> 5. Using your `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect_uri`, and the activation code from Step 4, post a request to the [Google's OAuth2
>      Token machine](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token). Make sure you include `grant_type =
>      "authorization_code"` in your post fields.
> 6. Hurray, you now have a `refresh_token` that never expires, and a working `access_token`! Post a request to the [Google's OAuth2 Token
>      machine](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token) with your `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect_uri`,
>      and `refresh_token` when your `access_token` expires and you'll get a
>      new one.

Comment: I can't find where to: "Visit your GA Admin and add this email as a user to your properties"

Should i just add that email to my existing emails under account overviews?

Comment: @dubbe After clicking the link above, choose an account, go to the _Users_ tab, and press the _New User_ button.

Comment: In the version I just got off SVN, some things have changed. apiClient() -> Google_Client(), apiAssertionCredentials -> Google_AssertionCredentials, apiAnalyticsService -> Google_AnalyticsService.. Basically, 'api...' now is 'Google_...'. (Same for the includes)

Comment: I've just posted an updated version of the code as another answer in this post for the new trunk svn version since all class & function names have changed.

Comment: @TerrySeidler thanks for the tip, I've updated the answer accordingly :)

Comment: Thank You so much! I would have lost a lot of time and probably given up if it hadn't been for your post and especially the update. I started with the "Hello Analytics API" tutorial (https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) and I re-used some of their code. For those who do, don't forget to set $client->setUseObjects(true); @rkarbowski I owe you a beer ;) Next time you're in Paris!

Comment: @Sébastien glad the post helped! and I will totally take you up on that offer ;)

Comment: I get 'invalid email address' when adding the ######@developer.gserviceaccount.com email address. Any ideas?

Comment: This answer was incredibly helpful. I couldn't find a single other example of a service account used with Google Analytics in several hours of searching.

Comment: @FlynSan ##### was just an example: your true email is unique and found in the API Access section of your app in the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

Comment: @rkarbowski Yes I'm aware. I used the Email given to me and got that message.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in Python?

Comment: upvoted, after reading zillions of posts and "sure working tutorials" without success, this made my code working in few minutes. THANKS.

Comment: Just as a quick note, the class "Google_AssertionCredentials" is now "Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials" in the latest php api client (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @David, I went ahead and updated everything to the latest API library on github (instead of SVN)

Comment: Brilliant! Google needs to document this much better

Comment: Did you ever come across this error :  Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php on line 33

Comment: @rohan-patel Add `require_once 'path/to/src/Google/autoload.php';`.

Answer (score 4):

The Google API PHP Client now supports service accounts on trunk.

The implementation hasn't been released yet, so you'll need to [checkout](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/checkout) the latest version of the PHP client.

I've prepared a sample application that demonstrates how you can use service accounts to hit the Google Prediction API.
To view the example, take a peek at examples/prediction/serviceAccount.php or visit:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/prediction/serviceAccount.php

Comment: Chirag, I had to un-accept your answer as further research reveals that [most Google APIs do not support service accounts yet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/NBQoOrtcC6A). Using an OAuth2 access token from a .P12 signed JWT results in a forbidden error from the Analytics API.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Google's PHP client API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) then go to the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and click on `API Access` on the left.

Then `Create a Client ID`. That will give you the `secret` and it is where you set your `redirect URL`. It won't give you a redirect URL - that is the URL the app sends the user back to after authenticating.

There are [other authentication methods](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v2/gdataAuthentication.html) you can look at.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As stated previously, I'm using my app as what Google describes as a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount), i.e. there is no end used involved. When I set up my application as such in the Google API Console, no secret was generated, and there was no prompt for me to enter redirect URL. That makes sense; there is no end-user in this application flow. Also, I would prefer to use the Core Reporting API v3 if possible.

Answer (score 2):

you can use very usefull php library [GAPI](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) (Google Analytics API PHP Interface) to access Google Analytics without OAuth. It's easy to use.