# GData Authentication for Server Apps

Tags: c#, gdata, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I have an application running on a server that periodically extracts data from Google Analytics. It doesn't issue many queries so I don't think any limit would be a problem.

I have a prototype running, however I had to provide a login a password for the authentication (in code).

I see that I can generate API keys and other kind of authentication bits and pieces in the Google APIs Console, however I am not sure how to use them and whether they can be used in place of the login/password.

It just doesn't seem right to use a user login/password to authenticate a server application.

Is there another way?

(I am using the C# client library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using OAuth 2.0. See:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs

for a sample OAuth workflow.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. Though this solution requires user interaction to grant the application (short term) access to the API, so I combined this with a hard-coded 'refresh token'. Not sure if this is the right way to go or if I should be using the Simple API Access (API Key) instead?

Comment: get a refresh token and use that. Simple API Access is only for "user-less" APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with Google Service Accounts
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

However, I don't know off the top of my head the best library for c#, but there does appear to be support for it in the Google library. http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts

Here's a answer specifically about the PHP client.
[Service Applications and Google Analytics API V3: Server-to-server OAuth2 authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863509/service-applications-and-google-analytics-api-v3-server-to-server-oauth2-authen)