# Google Analytics Core Reporting API with email and password for PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I used GAPI http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/ so far to get some data out of Google Analytics with PHP. 
With that you could use something like:

```
$ga = new gapi($User, $Password);
```

to login to Analytics and pull the data very easy.

But now the GAPI-Support has been canceled, and you have to use https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/ to access the data. But on all examples they use a method where the user has to do the login in a webbrowser to gain access. But I have a script on a webserver and I only have `$User` and `$Password`... So could someone please give me an example on how to do authenticate the user with that in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth has a flow called [*Client Credentials Grant*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.4). Google implements this with so called [*Service Accounts*](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#service_accounts), where you get a *client ID* and a *certificate file* instead of a *username/password* combination.

For using a *Service Account* to request authorization to the *Google Analytics API*, just follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089698/1467115).