# google api - server to server auth can access but not expected data

Tags: php, google-api

I've managed to get oauth 2 access with a refresh token. I'm using the calendar service and am able to retrieve a list of my calendars and events from a calendar.
I'm now testing using server to server authentication and have created and downloaded a key. However when I try and get a list of calendars I only get one entry relating to the id created by the server to server access. 
The calendars from my account don't appear.

It looks as if the server to server authentication is not accessing the full account I was expecting.

Have I missed something in the set up to see the full list of calendars?

I tried also accessing analytics using the same access but returning an error no analytic accounts set up when there are.

Any help or guidance appreciated of why the two types of access (refresh token or server key) produce different results for t apparently the same account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

I discovered the problem. THe server to server authentication creates a unique id ad email for the access. To access data on my main google account as expected I need to add this email account to the calendars authorised users from within the calendar settings.

When you set up the server to server key the user_email will look similar to:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Go into calendar, settings and then under each calendar > calendar settings > calendars change the sharing options. Add this email address and set appropriate user access

I've now been able to access the calendars with the server to server access and the key!

Thanks to this post for the clues:[Service Applications and Google Analytics API V3: Server-to-server OAuth2 authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863509/service-applications-and-google-analytics-api-v3-server-to-server-oauth2-authen)