# Server to server OAuth2

Tags: go, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-go-client

I'm trying to implement a Golang application for accessing Google Analytics data. but all the examples uses tokens that dies in one hour.
In the api access i found a "Certificate access" that are designed to be used to access from servers, but i failed to find examples of its implementation in Golang. there is some reading or may you can enlighten my path for this?

I'm using this library.
    code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/

reading some post here I found this [Service Applications and Google Analytics API V3: Server-to-server OAuth2 authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863509/service-applications-and-google-analytics-api-v3-server-to-server-oauth2-authen)

but it seems that it will not work directly. is really no way of doing this w/o hacking it around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked out the [OAuth2](https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/) package? I've used it for user-authorised calls, and hacked it around a bit to allow it to handle multiple authorisation sources.

I haven't tested it with pure server-to-server comms, but you should be able to hack the transport code to get it to do what it needs...

Answer (score 0):

this might be a little late but I havent found a good example to get people started.

Before you start make sure you

> install golang 1.5
>
> install google cloud SDK (cloud.google.com/sdk - this will allow for local development)
>
> Create a service account in your google appengine / cloud console and download the json (API's and auth > Credentials )

Once above is setup:

> set a path for your security credentials that you downloaded earlier
>
> export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/DIRECTORY/CREDENTIALS.json

now you can authenticate with go.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "golang.org/x/net/context"
  "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
   analytics "google.golang.org/api/analytics/v3"
)

var (
  scope = analytics.AnalyticsReadonlyScope 
)

func main() {
  // Authentication is provided by the gcloud tool when running locally, and
  // by the associated service account when running on Compute Engine.
  client, err := google.DefaultClient(context.Background(), scope)
  if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to get default client: %v", err)
  }

  service, err := analytics.New(client)
  if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to create storage service: %v", err)
  }

  fmt.Println(service)
}
```