# Getting data from a analytics account using Google Analytics API and PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a backoffice for a website in PHP.

In that backoffice I would like to output some google analytics info refering to that site. And only that site.

For that, I looked into the google analytics API, but I'm having some problems that I don't know if can overcome.

I don't want the API to ask for the user to login or authorization.
I want the API to access always the same account (mine) and not another google analytics account, so no authorization required.

Can that be done?
Can someone point me to a good tutorial about using the API in the context I'm looking for?

Thank You.

Comment: Check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com.  If your backoffice all uses the same GA account we have a "CMS" version which allows you to do exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the regular API; as you mentioned, it requires the user to login.  However, you can do this with the [Google Analytics superProxy API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy).

Comment: actually you can without login. see my reply below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it's possible.

You **CAN** connect directly to the API without it asking for authorization.

See:
[Service Applications and Google Analytics API V3: Server-to-server OAuth2 authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863509/service-applications-and-google-analytics-api-v3-server-to-server-oauth2-authen/10089698#10089698)

Comment: +1 aah interesting, i'll give that a try some time. THE MORE YOU KNOW