# Google Analytics Reports Embed API returns 403 error

Tags: api, google-analytics, report, embed, google-reporting-api

I just started to learn about Google Analytics Embed API from "https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started"

I followed their example, and deployed my HTML file onto local Tomcat server hosting at port 8080. I've added everything they mentioned including the whitelists for the host origin etc, provided my OAuth 2.0 key

when I hit my HTML page and logged in with google, I keep on getting 403 error when requesting for "https://content.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries?max-results=0&_src=embed-api%3Av1"

Anybody has any suggestions where I might have gone wrong?

p.s. the only thing I see on my page after login with Google is "You are logged in as: ***********@gmail.com"

Thanks,

Shen

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking your link, I can see that the error code is 401. Regarding that error, you can check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586590/google-analytics-api-returning-401-on-example-code).

I think you need to set up a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) as advised in answer.

> By setting up a service account in [Google apis console](https://cloud.google.com/console/project?redirected=true) it will
>   allow you to access your own data with out needing to login and
>   autenticate the code all the time.