# Google API oAuth 2.0 - script run from command line

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I want to run a daily cronjob to load data from Google Analytics into my database. I want to use PHP and oAuth 2.0.

I assume that this case would be considered a Web Server Application (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=de#webserver)

But in all examples I find it uses the typical, a user clicks on a 'connect to Google' button, browser rediretcs to Google where the user has to login and authorize the request.

But I want to run this from the command line and the user is always me. I guess this is not very diferente from the browser approach but I am a little confused on where to start neither how to formulate this into a real question.

Does anyone have tutorials especificaly about this or any other help?

Thanks!

EDIT: The first time I have to get the token and the refresh token. Is there any other may to get this then over the google popup in the browser? Or do I have to make a little html page to run this once to get the token and refresh token? Still confused.

[image]

Comment: 4. Refresh the access token, if necessary.

Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.

Comment: Are you only accessing your own GA Data? or data owned by other users?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863509/service-applications-and-google-analytics-api-v3-server-to-server-oauth2-authen Check this solution