# How to use google oauth on a plugin on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-oauth

I want to develop a plugin for wordpress, this plugin will be used in a lot of websites that they will buy it and install it.

On this plugin I want to use google oauth to get datas from analytics, But I have to define the callbackURL in my console and in the code, But I can't know which website will install my plugin.

Please if you have any Ideas how to it help me to get this done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service Applications and Google Analytics API V3: Server-to-server OAuth2 authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863509/service-applications-and-google-analytics-api-v3-server-to-server-oauth2-authen)

Comment: @jpaljasma  service application can not be used for wordpress plugin, It is an installed-app where as service application is used when you you want to see or show your data, how people will use how your plugin will know which website data I should display ?